# JAVA API Servlet Asynchronous Call

Tags: java, servlets, asynchronous

I wanted to conduct an asynchronous call in Java API Servlet. I used this at the top of my class

```
  @WebServlet(name="asyncServlet2",value = {"/async"},asyncSupported = true,urlPatterns="/async")
```

My intention is since the API call will be a longer process that it can display whether the process kicked off or not instantly, rather than when completed.

I couldn't figure out which functionality of the Java Servlet 3.0 will let me display the message instantly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note that even though the request is handled asynchronously, it's still one request/response cycle.

Comment: So can't I confirm the request kicked-off successfully before finishing and giving the response back?

Comment: Ajax is probably better suited for this. Otherwise, the confirmation would be part of the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what the response is expected to look like. If you are in full control over how the response should look, this should be feasible. For example:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    AsyncContext context = req.startAsync();

    // Possibly in another thread:

    // Initiate call to external service.

    resp.getWriter().write("Call initiated OK.\n\n");
    resp.getWriter().flush();

    // Definitely in another thread:

    // Call to external service returns.

    resp.getWriter().write("Result: " + result);
    resp.getWriter().flush();
    context.complete();
}
```

Note that the response will come back as 200 OK even though the call to external service might fail in the end.